# Can CFMutablePathRef be autoReleased?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I have a class returning mutable pathRef's from class methods like this:

```
    + (CGMutablePathRef)roundedRectanglePathInRectangle:(CGRect)rect withCornerRadius:(float)radius{

      CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();

      float x = rect.origin.x;
      float y = rect.origin.y;
      float w = rect.size.width;
      float h = rect.size.height;

      if (radius > w / 2) {
        radius = w / 2;
      }
      if (radius > h / 2) {
        radius = h / 2;
      }

      CGPoint tl = CGPointMake(x + radius, y + radius);
      CGPoint tr = CGPointMake(x + w -radius, y +radius);
      CGPoint br = CGPointMake(x + w -radius, y + h -radius);
      CGPoint bl = CGPointMake(x + radius, y + h -radius);


      CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, x, tl.y);
      CGPathAddArc(pathRef, nil, tl.x, tl.y, radius, M_PI, 3*M_PI/2, 0);
      CGPathAddArc(pathRef, nil, tr.x, tr.y, radius, 3*M_PI/2, 0, 0);
      CGPathAddArc(pathRef, nil, br.x, br.y, radius, 0, M_PI/2, 0);
      CGPathAddArc(pathRef, nil, bl.x, bl.y, radius, M_PI/2, M_PI, 0); 

      CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, x, tl.y);



      return pathRef;
      CGPathRelease(pathRef);

    }
```

now because the last line (release) is after the (return) it is never called and I have a leak.  Does anyone have a way to make this CGPath autorelease?

thanks so much :)

Comment: Release your CGMutablePathRef after you call this function you built.

Comment: thanks Claudio.  What if i stack em up in one pathRef? can they be released enMasse? (see my comments below.. thanks so much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't. You can tell from the "CF" prefix that that type belongs to Core Foundation, which doesn't have an equivalent to Foundation's autoRelease. In some cases, there are toll-free bridges between Foundation classes (like NSString) and Core Foundation types (like CFStringRef) that will let you work around this fact, but CFPath and its mutable counterpart are not toll-free-bridged to any Foundation class.

You'll have to CFRelease your mutable path after you call the method. You should probably name your method according to memory management conventions that indicate that the caller owns the returned value, and is therefore responsible for releasing it when done.

Comment: thanks Matt, its pretty much what i suspected.   So just to be 100% clear.  if I have a CGPathRelease after I use it I can defeat the leak (ie the leak is not coming from this 'pathmaker' class. ?

Comment: lets say I use CGPathAddPath to stack a few up..

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddPath(path, nil, [pathmaker roundedRectPathInRect:rect1 withCornerRadius:r1]);
CGPathAddPath(path, nil, [pathmaker roundedRectPathInRect:rect2 withCornerRadius:r2]);
//etc

will CGPathRelease(path); be sufficient? or must I write each path into its own pathRef for individual releasing?  thanks so much, sorry if its a stupid question :)

Comment: @Jef, Your guiding rule should be to balance *every* call to this function with a CFRelease on the returned path, since every call allocates and returns a new CGMutablePath. So, in your example of adding successive paths, you'll need to store each path in variable, add it, and then release it. It's unfortunately verbose...

Comment: !!GAk!!!

looks like Ive got a few lines of flippin code to type grrr

thanks so much you're a champion

Comment: @Jef, yes you do. Good luck =)

Comment: I got this working great at the time and Thanks so much Matt.   Can you give me any clues about the 'memory management conventions' you mention?   How would you name such a method so that others would understand that they will owe a CGPathRelease ? Thanks again

Comment: @Jef, the convention I mention is outlined in the Core Foundation Memory Management Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH". It's pretty simple; Apple says that functions whose names contain either "Create" or "Copy" indicate that the caller owns the returned memory.

Comment: Ah so!! put 'create' in the method name! its so obvious it makes me sick.  Thanks so much have a great day

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do:

`return ((CGPathRef)[(__bridge id)somePathRef autorelease]);`